# Mongo db array changing string to float

Tags: mongodb

Now, I can find 'versions.0.content.axdducvoxb' 
with quotes but i don't know how I have to write 
parseFloat(data.versions.0.content.axdducvoxb)

I try to use code for string -> number conversions in MongoDB. I do this for using aggregate

It works:

```
db.documents.find().forEach(function(data) {
    db.documents.update({_id:data._id},{$set:{axdducvoxb:parseFloat(data.axdducvoxb)}});
})
```

I have array with versions, and it doesn't work:

```
>     db.documents.find().forEach(function(data) {
>     db.documents.update({_id:data._id},{$set:{versions.0.content.axdducvoxb:parseFloat(data.versions.0.content.axdducvoxb)}});
> })
```

I see error like this: 27 14:14:58.543 SyntaxError: Unexpected number

Please tell me what I have to do )))

**First answer does not work (((**

If I correct query and try it:

```
db.documents.find().forEach(function(data) {   db.documents.update({_id:data._id},{$set:{"versions.0.content.axdducvoxb":parseFloat(data.versions.0.content.axdducvoxb)}}}); })
    Mon Mar 31 13:23:45.474 SyntaxError: Unexpected number
```

If I add quotes for both indexes I clean the base:

```
db.documents.find().forEach(function(data) {   db.documents.update({_id:data._id},{$set:{"versions.0.content.axdducvoxb":parseFloat("data.versions.0.content.axdducvoxb")}}}); })
```

I need to transform all strings with numbers to float )))

**I did it!!! May be somebody need the same....**

**My code for String to Float conversion in mongo DB console (4 examples):**

```
db.documents.find({ 'fwtweaeeba' : {$exists : true}}).forEach( function(obj) { obj.fwtweaeeba = parseFloat( obj.fwtweaeeba ); db.documents.save(obj); } ); 

db.documents.find({ 'versions.0.content.fwtweaeeba' : {$exists : true}}).forEach( function(obj) { obj.versions[0].content.fwtweaeeba = parseFloat( obj.versions[0].content.fwtweaeeba ); db.documents.save(obj); } ); 

db.documents.find({ 'versions.1.content.fwtweaeeba' : {$exists : true}}).forEach( function(obj) { obj.versions[1].content.fwtweaeeba = parseFloat( obj.versions[1].content.fwtweaeeba ); db.documents.save(obj); } ); 

db.documents.find({ 'versions.2.content.fwtweaeeba' : {$exists : true}}).forEach( function(obj) { obj.versions[2].content.fwtweaeeba = parseFloat( obj.versions[2].content.fwtweaeeba ); db.documents.save(obj); } );
```

**PHP script to conversion string to float in collection (all strings I need):**

```
<?php
$fieldNamesToFloat = array(
         "atkswlntfd",
         "auwbsjqzir",
         "avqrnjzbgd",
         "awquatbduv",
         "axdducvoxb",
         "bkoldugcrp",
         "bzccjslewi",
         "cclwyezydc",
         "covfctuuhi",
         "dingrnyknr",
         "dkfknpzsnt",
         "dqetuhllse",
         "duorlxiqbw",
         "eayoicezsh",
         "esrfffruoy",
         "ewdunlkxue",
         "ewfshjnome",
         "exakqiudxg",
         "fabdcybqxu",
         "fsplxunmaf",
         "fubxmogyam",
         "fuzqrnwsks",
         "fwtweaeeba",
         "fybnnlojgb",
         "gdjheqrqcx",
         "gpupstzwjd",
         "gxilphzzcu",
         "hbahrruokf",
         "hbqnleclwp",
         "hchpoxxnwz",
         "hmorfnbfvf",
         "hqatnzynxb",
         "hrqssioxdv",
         "hvscavwupe",
         "hyzlbtnxil",
         "idzxqjoxgd",
         "ikxsvguboy",
         "ipjpwkbqnt",
         "izqighabwk",
         "jncncbplme",
         "jxkspszlrc",
         "kekarveuhb",
         "klyoglzriu",
         "kmvuelmdwe",
         "knxzfjwnax",
         "kqfhjboecc",
         "kqhojbwvmo",
         "lchogmhynm",
         "lmuwyeqvph",
         "lvcdbhisbx",
         "mijczjeqeo",
         "mpxzquzcat",
         "mqqoetqued",
         "muktdrzphw",
         "nceszojuvt",
         "nypnjqgxop",
         "ojklibfieg",
         "padotysmxb",
         "pidwyruvfq",
         "pkeymzxsrj",
         "pnjtfvzwiv",
         "pqjnpoxmcx",
         "pyexnkjujx",
         "qfeqdvzssg",
         "qidslfqnwn",
         "qvjszkahdc",
         "qzoriqedoh",
         "rjicuyfsmt",
         "rqenalbuko",
         "rxkwogbxwu",
         "sbqqabqukn",
         "skhgbmucrp",
         "slewjrvgjn",
         "tidjarsatz",
         "tmbagkmlgb",
         "uqcdessbeu",
         "vacoxpronz",
         "vdjfydjrpa",
         "vktxndqyhm",
         "vmfqvfjptu",
         "vofeebpgsc",
         "wewmtafjvk",
         "wfqdcsrltv",
         "wzmbxalguv",
         "xjllpdyool",
         "xjxbwynytx",
         "xmirihwycl",
         "xxrsnjlmfv",
         "ybgdjpexth",
         "ymkmkuxlrq",
         "yneoycjloj",
         "yogujlfvpb",
         "zahigfmqxb",
         "znqqhqkjte",
         "zyztudtziu"
);
$m = new MongoClient();
$db = $m->foo_data;
$collection = new MongoCollection($db, 'documents');
foreach($fieldNamesToFloat as $fieldName){
    foreach($db->documents->find(array("type" => "chair")) as $document){
        $db->documents->update(
            array('_id' => $document[_id]),
            array(
                '$set' => array(
                    'versions.0.content.'.$fieldName => (float)$document['versions'][0]['content'][$fieldName],
                    'versions.1.content.'.$fieldName => (float)$document['versions'][1]['content'][$fieldName],
                    'versions.2.content.'.$fieldName => (float)$document['versions'][2]['content'][$fieldName],
                    $fieldName => (float)$document[$fieldName]
                )
            ),
            array('$multi' => true)
        );
    }
}
echo "well done";      
?>
```

Comment: what is  the value of data.axdducvoxb. Print in console

Comment: When using dot `.` notation you need yo quote as in `"versions.0.content.axdducvoxb"`

Comment: Umm... you're not using aggregate at all here...

Comment: I prepare db to use aggregate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try wrapping $set value in quotes as shown below:

```
"versions.0.content.axdducvoxb":parseFloat(data.versions.0.content.axdducvoxb)
```

Final result:

```
db.documents.find().forEach(function(data) {
  db.documents.update({_id:data._id},{$set:"versions.0.content.axdducvoxb":parseFloat(data.versions.0.content.axdducvoxb)}});
})
```

---

Whenever you use this dot notation, you are required to wrap the key in quotes as mentioned in [the documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#dot-notation) (emphasis added):

> To access an element of an array by the zero-based index position, concatenate the array name with the dot (.) and zero-based index position, **and enclose in quotes**

Comment: Good answer! Wherever possible, it is preferred to back your claim with some reference to the documentation. I've added it for you.