# How to find within a embedded document of Mongodb a key if it?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-java

```js
{
   _id: "joe",
   name: "Joe Bookreader",
   addresses: [
                {
                  street: "123 Fake Street",
                  city: "Faketon",
                  state: "MA",
                  zip: "12345"
                },
                {
                  street: "1 Some Other Street",
                  city: "Boston",
                  state: "MA",
                  zip: "12345"
                }
              ]
 }
```

How to find the key street if it exists in this document?

Comment: Meaning what exactly? Do you want to find a particular street? Do just want to find if it exists? There is not a lot here to describe what you want to do, or what you have even tried.

Comment: I want to find the key 'street' if it exists or not,without specifying its value. I want all the records in the collection in which there is key street. I have tried db.collection.find({ addresses.street: { $exists: true}}), but seems dot(.) doesn't work with $exists operator

Comment: This might help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22761423/mongo-db-array-changing-string-to-float/22761736#22761736

Comment: @LalitAgarwal Why? That is not even related, perhaps you commented on the wrong question.

Comment: I would suggest that much as shown in the answer given you forgot to quote the field when using `dot` notation

Comment: @NeilLunn Well, it would solve his problem that's all I know. Thanks for the advice anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use $exists operator:

```
db.yourCollectionName.find( { 'addresses.street': { $exists: true } } );
```

Comment: Thanks! Artem i forgot to apply quotes. @Neil Thanks!